# What is the use of Netty in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, netty

I am a newbie in elastic-search.
I am a web developer with very less networking experience.

I have read the following documents -

```
https://netty.io/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839437/what-are-the-netty-alternatives-for-high-performance-networking
```

I wasn't able to understand the purpose of netty for elastic search. Could anyone explain it to me in layman terms?

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch offers two interfaces to talk to it. One is the HTTP interface and the other one is the transport interface.

The first usually runs on port 9200 and can be accessed via any HTTP capable tool e.g. `curl` or your favorite browser. The transport interface is used by cluster members to exchange data and state and runs on port 9300 using a custom protocol.

Both interfaces use netty as "socket / NIO" library.